# Getting Unexpected templating type error occurred while assigning value to set_fact with Ansible

Tags: ansible

Getting Unexpected templating type error occurred while assigning value to set_fact with Ansible

Below is my playbook:

```
   - name: Load entire repository inventory
     include_vars:
       file="{{ playbook_dir }}/repository/inform/gac.yaml"
       name=user1

   - debug:
       msg: "ALERT !! File {{ user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] }} has changed {{ inventory_hostname }}"
     when: item.stat.checksum != user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path].hash
     with_items: "{{ files_det.results }}"


   - name: Gather all files
     tags: always
     set_fact:
       msg_body: "{{ msg_body | default('') + user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] + 'has changed' + inventory_hostname +'. Rollback' + '\n' }}"
     when: item.stat.checksum != user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path].hash
     with_items: "{{ files_det.results }}"
```

I recieve error with set_fact as below:

```
"msg": "ALERT !! File {u'hash': u'1746f03d5741b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2'} has changed 10.9.9.66"


TASK [Gather all files] ***************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/fg_test.yml:2
META: noop
fatal: [10.9.9.66]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ msg_body | default('') + user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] + 'has changed' + [inventory_hostname] +'. Rollback' + '\n' }}): cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects"
}
META: noop
```

I even tried

```
   msg_body: "{{ msg_body | default('') + user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] + 'has changed' + [inventory_hostname] +'. Rollback' + '\n' }}"
```

but that too did not help.

Can you please suggest what is the issue with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"What is the issue with my code ?"*

A: The issue is "`Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects`".

Quoting from your code below, it can be seen that `user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path]` is **dictionary** `{u'hash': u'1746f03d5741b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2'}`

```
   - debug:
       msg: "ALERT !! File {{ user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] }} has changed {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

```
"msg": "ALERT !! File {u'hash': u'1746f03d5741b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2'} has changed 10.9.9.66"
```

In the next step you **concatenate strings with this dictionary**.

```
msg_body: "{{ msg_body | default('') + user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path] + 'has changed'
```

Fix it. Replace the dictionary with the string. For example use

```
user1[inventory_hostname][item.stat.path.hash]
```

Comment: How can i concat a dictionary to a string?

Comment: I don't want to add hash but i want to add `item.stat.path` to the `set_fact`. Is it possible to convert dictionary to a string and concatenate using `+` ??